# Auxiliary View to Isometric Projection (3D)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, technical-drawing

I'm having a hard time to visualize this Auxiliary View into Isometric Projection or the 3D version, my friend said that it shape like a hinge, but I stil could not visualize it, can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quickly done, not in exact scale as ive eyeballed it

[image]

Like a bent hinge is a good desctription